# Excel VBA Copy specific Column from different Worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently developing a monitoring Tool in Excel using VBA and encountered some difficulties when copying data.

Current Code:

```
Sub CopyID()
    'Copies entire Row of IDs from "Sheet 2" to main Sheet "Main Sheet"

    Dim lastCell As Long
    LastCell = Cells(Rows.Count,'Sheet 2':M).End(xlUp).Row

    'Missing here: Copy to Column 1 at Row 3!

    Sheets("Sheet 2").Columns(M).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Main Sheet").Columns(1)

End Sub
```

What it is supposed to do:
Copy the Data of Sheet2_Column M starting at Row 2 
to
Main Sheet Colum A sarting at Row 3

Also, I don't know if this is possible yet, use a specific formula for the destination (Formular is: `=LEFT(Data,10)`)

I am glad for any response to this as I'd like to learn how these "Copy Methods" work in detail and am happy for any tipps and tricks regarding these methods.

Edit//
The Copy Part should work like this

Sheet 2 Contains a Colum that has a headercell and X cells with a value that has a similar format.

Example of the Sheet 2 Contents

[image: Example of the Sheet 2 Contents]

This is a row in Sheet 2. I only need the first 10 digits of the content of the cells. Is it possible to include that as a formula similar to

```
=Left(Sheet 2:M2,10)
```

so it works like this:

"sheet 2" cell content: "1234567891_1_123X" copy to "main sheet" as "1234567891"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your source and destination worksheet. And range/column names bust be submitted as strings like `"M"`.

```
Sub CopyID()
    'Copies entire Row of IDs from "Sheet 2" to main Sheet "Main Sheet"
    Dim WsSource As Worksheet
    Set WsSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet 2")    

    Dim WsDestination As Worksheet
    Set WsDestination = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main Sheet")    


    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = WsSource.Cells(WsSource.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row

    'Missing here: Copy to Column 1 at Row 3!

    WsSource.Range("M2:M" & lastRow).Copy Destination:=WsDestination.Range("A3")
End Sub
```

---

Edit:

To copy only the first 10 characters of each cell would need a process for each value:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CopyID()
    'Copies entire Row of IDs from "Sheet 2" to main Sheet "Main Sheet"
    Dim WsSource As Worksheet
    Set WsSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet 2")

    Dim WsDestination As Worksheet
    Set WsDestination = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main Sheet")

    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = WsSource.Cells(WsSource.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row 'Find last row in column M

    Dim ArrSource As Variant
    ArrSource = WsSource.Range("M2:M" & lastRow).Value 'read column m values into array

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(ArrSource) 'process each value in the array
        ArrSource(i, 1) = Left$(ArrSource(i, 1), 10) 'keep only left 10 characters
    Next i

    WsDestination.Range("A3").Resize(UBound(ArrSource), 1).Value = ArrSource 'write array into destination
End Sub
```

Note `.Resize(UBound(ArrSource), 1)` defines the destination the same size as the array is that we want to insert.

Comment: That worked like a charm, many Thanks. I did not know that you need to submit columns as strings, thanks for the note. Is it possible to edit the way the selection is pasted @ `Destination:=WsDestination` using a formula?

Comment: You said you want to use the formula `=LEFT(Data,10)`. What is `Data` here? Is it a named range? And what is the value of `Data`?

Comment: `Data`is the Content of the copied Cell. The cell contains a string similar to `1234567891_1_123X` It's a database generated string, and I cannot edit the way it is exported, I only need the first 10 numbers untill the first underscore.

Comment: I don't see how this number defines a destination as this number is not a valid address of a cell. Please be much more specific what you are trying to do. Best explain it in your original question as there you got more space than in a comment.

Comment: I've edited the question to show it. Sorry that I was not specific enough, english is not my native language ^^. Its only visible till its been peer reviewed though.

Comment: @Ninsa No worries, but please always edit your own question instead of anyone's answer. This site is question/answer based not like a continuous forum so everything you ask must be in your question, so anyone can post answers. I moved your edit to your question already. Let me have a look.

Comment: Oh Sorry, I've pressed the wrong button in excitement. Apologies.

Comment: Question again: Did I understand it correctly that you want to copy the first 10 characters of each cell in `Sheet 2` column M into `Main Sheet` column A?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The First 10 digits are all that need to be copied.

Comment: @Ninsa this would be a complete change of the approach, because you cannot just copy. Instead you need to process each cell value. See my edit.

Comment: @Peh That makes sense, It works absolutely perfectly. I need to look further into it as I do not quite understand what is happening but I get the requirement to process each cell seperately. Thanks a ton! That really helped me and I learned quite a lot from it.

Comment: @Ninsa feel free to ask what you don't figure out to understand.

Comment: Did i get it right that you copy the values into an Array, then edit the values in that array to match my formula approach, then copy the values in a preselected area in my main worksheet wich is exactly as big as the array? If so, I guess it is needed to preselect that area to be as big as the array to prevent loss of data?

Comment: @Ninsa Yes, that's all correct. The preselected area needs to be exactly the same size as the array. If you preselect less than the array size you will lose data. `UBound(ArrSource)` gives you the upper bound (size) of the array and `Range("A3").Resize(rows, columns)` sizes starting at A3 and resizes by the given amount of rows and columns. • Using arrays is much faster then reading each cell one by one, process it and write it back one by one, because each read/write take its time. But the array reads/writes all cells at once which makes it so fast to process.